# Facebook access token send to server with every request

Tags: session, oauth, client-server, facebook-login, access-token

So I have an android app that has login with facebook enabled. Once the user logs in, the app sends the user's access token over to the server for verification. The server verifies the validity of the token by making a simple request to facebook using that access token.

Now after this initial verification, I need to verify every subsequent request that the client android app makes to the server to identify the client. Should I  include the access token in the body of every request (POST request), and confirm that it matches the access token received in the login process above? What about GET requests?

*Update: I need to maintain a session on the client (android app) and the server so the server recognizes the client. In my case, lets say two different users are logged in and both are making GET requests to the server. My server doesn't know who the user is since I don't have a session which can persist on the android app by just creating a session variable in rails - the client's app needs to have the same session variable as the server. But I don't know how to do that without sending the access token, or the @user.id with every request back and forth and back again...Wondering if there's a better way to do this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens being passed with every request and being verified on the server is the standard solution.
Irrespective, of the HTTP method, it is again a standard practice to send the token as a HTTP Header.

While you're at it use the standard OAuth2 header for sending across tokens 'Bearer'. Like below.

```
Bearer: 8QIEF9QWEDFCQERMF0139RF1E=
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it make sense to send the same unencrypted FB access token back and forth? I mean are there any safety considerations?

Comment: Is your site not HTTPS? If yes, the data including the headers are anyways encrypted so no need to encrypt again. If it is not, I would recommend you use HTTPS else you will need to encrypt the token. But encrypting yourself is not recommended as you will need share the key between the server and the app and its a maintenance nightmare. Also if you think the answer is correct can you please mark it so.